# Create subsite/team site with Default Permissions Group and Custom Groups?

Tags: 2013, permissions, sharepoint-on-prem, team-sites

I am using SP2013 OnPrem.

I would like to know if there is a way without using PowerShell [I don't have access to it or the farm] to set custom default groups for team sites [ex: Leadership, Elevated Members] and have new sites created use the default SP groups created for new sites [i.e. Site Name Owners, Site Name Members...]?

Answer (score 3):

Handling SharePoint without Powershell, that is a challenge. However in this case you might be able to create a site, update it as required and save it as a template ( unless it is a publishing site)

Comment: Lol who are you telling.  My head hurts trying to figure out ways to workaround things without PowerShell D;.  I'll try this route.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be admin of the content, but haven't permissions as Farm Admininstrator, they can set you

- with **User Policy** on Web Applications  with permisisons Full Control. [Link Here.](http://www.sharepointdiary.com/2016/08/configuring-web-application-user-policies-in-sharepoint-2013-2016.html)
- or as **Site Collection Administrator**
- or as **Site Owner** by adding to Owners SharePoing Group.

Comment: Hi Zdenek, I'm already an SCA.  I don't think you understood the ask very well.  This has nothing to do with my permissions, rather I want to be able to have a project site inherit specific user groups at the top level site so that certain people have access to the content, yet still have the default 3 groups SP creates [Owners, Members, Visitors] so that whomever is designated as the Site Owner can manage their own crap.

Comment: So you want to delete the default 3 groups and replace them with... ? If you want to use same permissions on sub-webs just set inherited permissions. Yes i probably dont understand You.

Comment: Sorry about that. No, I don't want the 3 default groups deleted. I would like the default groups to remain, but add additional custom groups to the site.  I would like to automate the addition of the custom groups to the subsite upon initialization.  Does that make a bit more sense?  Apologies if I'm unclear.